# Advanced command line module in Python

Tags: python, command-line, drawing

I am looking for a python module to do some command line programming, e.g. I'm want something to set the cursor in the command line (so I can draw at a specific coordinate), capture input without echoing it, drawing in colors etc. I've been searching for a while now, but I can't find one. Does someone know such a module?

PS: It should work with Windows, but cross-platform is preferred.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want something for interactive use or programmatic use. Use Cairo for the latter.

Comment: I don't see how it can be unclear, but maybe that's just me. I just want something to program the visual command line output more efficiently. Like the crt module in Pascal, for example.

Comment: "python conio" googling brings up some related stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like (n)curses, or a library for it like [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) (a lot simpler).